# select box using jstl spring 4 MVC, mongodb

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, jstl

I am trying to make a select box using jstl throgh model view and i am a pure noob, someone i have gone through this and created this can anyone help me to get the monngodb values in select box

here are my codes

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getSpeciality", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public  ModelAndView getSpeciality(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        myModel.put("myVar", getSpeciality( UtilsManagementService.getSpeciality() )); // here is showing error UtilsManagementService cannot be resolved
        return new ModelAndView("view", myModel);
    }
```

Management layer

```
package com.geniedoc.management.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.geniedoc.exception.BussniessException;
import com.geniedoc.exception.UserNotFoundException;
import com.geniedoc.vo.CityVo;
import com.geniedoc.vo.SpecialityVO;


public interface UtilsManagementService {


    public List<SpecialityVO> getSpeciality(String key) throws BussniessException; }
```

DB

```
@Override
public Speciality getSpeciality(String specialityName) {
    Query findSpecialityQuery = new Query();
    findSpecialityQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(SPECIALITY_NAME).regex(specialityName));
    Speciality speciality = null;
    try{
        speciality = this.specialityRepository.getDocument(Speciality.class, findSpecialityQuery, SPECIALITY_TABLE);
    }catch(MongoDBDocumentNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return speciality;
}
```

and jsp

```
 <select id="Speciality" name=""Speciality"">
      <c:forEach var="item" items="${myModel}">
        <option value="${item.key}">${item.value}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Speciality Vo

```
package com.geniedoc.vo;

public class SpecialityVO {

    private int _id;
    private String speciality_name;
    private String speciality_description;
    public String getSpeciality_name() {
        return speciality_name;
    }
    public void setSpeciality_name(String speciality_name) {
        this.speciality_name = speciality_name;
    }
    public String getSpeciality_description() {
        return speciality_description;
    }
    public void setSpeciality_description(String speciality_description) {
        this.speciality_description = speciality_description;
    }
    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }




}
```

Comment: can you tell us the exact problem you are facing

Comment: @RamanaManoj at the very fisrt code it is showing error i alreadygiven that line that where it is giving the error // all i want to fetch the value from mongodb and populate the select tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject UtilsManagementService (which would have an Implementation) to your Controller. Define the bean and autowire it.

Then use the model which is return by the service.

I do not find any issues with your jstl code.